# Message box before closing worksheet to display name of all the unprotected sheets

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have done 2 separate prog till now.

One displays a message box before closing a workbook:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim answer As String
    Dim question As String
    question = "Display all the sheets which are Unprotected"
    answer = MsgBox(question, vbYesNo)

    If answer = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "complete everything and then close"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Another displays in a new sheet "Unprotected", list of all the unprotected sheets.

```
Sub UnprotectSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet, a As Range
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "Unprotected"
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 If ws.ProtectContents = False And ws.Name <> "Unprotected" Then
CNT = Sheets("Unprotected").Cells(Sheets("Unprotected").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Unprotected").Cells(CNT + 1, "A") = ws.Name
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I want a Message box to appear if I try to close the worksheet and if any sheet is unprotected, the message box displays the names of the unprotected sheets. I am facing problem in combining the above 2 codes.
I am not a VBA expert and I am trying it but unable to solve it.

Comment: Check my answer below, which displays the sheet names in message box. I also giveyou some code that you could use to simply force all sheets to be protected (which is probably better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this can show you a list of the unprotected sheets. However, it's probably better to just use VBA to force their protection, rather than prompting the user to do it (unless they need to provide a password for protection status).

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim answer As String
    Dim question As String
    Dim unprotected as String
    unprotected = GetUnprotectedSheets(ThisWorkbook)
    If unprotected <> vbNullString Then 
       MsgBox "Please protected the following worksheets before closing" & vbCRLF & unprotected
       Cancel = True
       Exit Sub
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub

Function GetUnprotectedSheets(wb as Workbook) 
'Custom function to return a string of sheet names
' which are unprotected
Dim ret as String
Dim ws as Worksheet
For each ws in wb.Worksheets
    If Not ws.ProtectContents Then
        ret = IIF(ret = "", ws.Name, ret & vbCRLF & ws.Name)
    End If
Next

GetUnprotectedSheets = ret

End Function
```

You can call a procedure like this to ensure all sheets are protected:

```
Sub ProtectAllSheets(wb as Workbook)
Dim ws as Worksheet
For each ws in wb.Worksheets
    If Not ws.ProtectContents Then ws.Protect
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David for your help but i am getting error while running the first code

Comment: Well I can't read your mind or see your screen, so it world help if you can tell me 1) what is the error message and 2) what line raises the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a counter to your second script:

```
Sub UnprotectSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet, a As Range
Dim iCounter As Integer, strMessage As String   'Adding a counter variable & string
'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "Unprotected"
iCounter = 0  'Initialize it
strMessage = "" 'Initialize empty string for the message box

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   If ws.ProtectContents = False Then
      iCounter = iCounter + 1    'Keeping track of any unprotected sheet
'      CNT = Sheets("Unprotected").Cells(Sheets("Unprotected").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'      Sheets("Unprotected").Cells(CNT + 1, "A") = ws.Name
      strMessage = strMessage & ws.Name & " "
   End If
Next
' Here you can do your msgbox or any other action if unprotected sheet detected


If iCounter > 0 Then
   MsgBox ("These sheets are unprotected: " & strMessage)
End If

End Sub
```

EDIT:

To enclose that within a button click: add an activeX button to your form, then:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'E.g. make the sub a commmandbutton_click() event

End Sub
```

Actually, when you add the button to your form, if you right-click on it you have the option "View code" - this will create an associated Commandbutton_click like I showed above.

Comment: I don't want to add an extra sheet named "Unprotected" in my workbook.
I want to display all the unprotected sheets in the message box.

Comment: Sorry - I just took your script as was above. Why did you add a sheet int he first place>?

Comment: Adding a sheet is for seperate purpose, but now i was trying to display all the unprotected sheets in the message box if i try to close the worksheet.
And i am unable to do it.

Comment: Ok got ya - the edited version will only check the unprotected sheet, and compose a string listing those. Then the msbox chose the string if there are some.

Comment: It is working fine but I want the message box to be displayed when i click on close button on Worksheet ...

Comment: You should probably link that script with the close button on the worksheet then - I don't think it would make sense to run that script, then somehow only display the message box later.

Comment: See modifications above

Comment: I think I should use : Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Comment: Or more simply, just add a call to Unprotectsheet() within your already existing BeforeWorkbook_Close(), e.g. within your first script.